# Export grid to excel on ascx page in SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying export grid to excel on ascx page in SharePoint web part solution. It throws following error

```
Control 'ctl00_ctl24_g_20574c20_e209_4887_ab02_83ee55a79fc5_ctl00_gdReport' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
```

To avoid this error I must use following method but then compiler throws an error saying "no suitable method found to override"

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control) { }
```

Full code:

```
protected void btnExcelExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   PrepareForExport(gdSharedReport); 
   ExportToExcel(); 
} 

private void ExportToExcel() 
{ 
   Response.Clear(); 
   Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.xls"); 
   Response.Charset = String.Empty; 
   Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"; 
   StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(); 
   HtmlTextWriter HtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter); 
   gdSharedReport.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter); 
   Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString()); 
   Response.End(); 
}

private void PrepareForExport(Control ctrl) 
{ 
   //iterate through all the grid controls 
   foreach (Control childControl in ctrl.Controls) 
   { 
      //if the control type is link button, remove it 
      //from the collection 
      if (childControl.GetType() == typeof(LinkButton)) 
      { 
         ctrl.Controls.Remove(childControl); 
      } 
      //if the child control is not empty, repeat the process 
      // for all its controls 
      else if (childControl.HasControls()) 
      { 
         PrepareForExport(childControl); 
      } 
   }  
}
```

Comment: For the first error, you are missing the `runat="Server"` attribute in your `.aspx` page.  For the second, you need to post more of the relevant code.  Are you sure that method can/needs to be overridden?

Comment: @Brian, Added full code. Please note I haven't use VerifyRenderingInServerForm() on the form. Also, My grid is placed on ascx page.

Comment: @jp2code , What do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Your post says:

To avoid this error I must use following method but then compiler throws an error saying "no suitable method found to override"

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control) { }
```

So, my guess is that you need to add the override to this **VerifyRenderingInServerForm** method.

Comment: I can't add VerifyRenderingInServerForm() on ascx page, it can be added only on aspx page.That's the problem here.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.deltapage.verifyrenderinginserverform.aspx) was no help (big surprise). Is [Export Gridview to Excel in Sharepoint (ascx)](http://forums.asp.net/t/1461411.aspx/1) doing what you need?

Comment: I saw this thread but there is no solution mentioned..I have exactly the same problem..

Comment: What kind of SharePoint project did you create? Sequential Workflow? Business Data Connectivity Model? Event Receiver? etc.

Comment: ,It's custom survey app.But I do work on all type of projects.

Comment: I'm just trying to recreate this in VS2010 on my end, but there are many SharePoint projects to start with. I'm thinking about getting a very basic SharePoint project in VS2010 with one of these ascx pages in it so I can see what is going on. I'd like to start with something similar to your project, but as basic as possible.

Comment: Just create test web part; add grid on ascx page with test data, put button and paste my code and deploy the web part. Open SP and add that web part onto the page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1959316/153923 That link says ascx is a control, and aspx is the webpage. Perhaps you named your page incorrectly.